# How can I clear these floated divs that are not the same height?

Tags: css, css-float

I have an image gallery where sometimes there is a caption below the image and sometimes there isn't. The image will always be the exact same size but the total height of the blocks are different because of the caption.

I have tried adding this to the blocks but it doesn't work.

```
.image-block:nth-child(odd):after {
  content:"";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

If I manually add a div.clear after the second block, this works. I'm not sure why it doesn't work to add it in the clear in the :after.

https://codepen.io/sharpdesigner/pen/VQRwxy

Comment: If the images are all the same width, you could try using a column based layout: just give the container the appropriate number of columns, like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVXmLy).

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).